# Why are my font-sizes changed by Outlook 2007, 10, 13, 16, 19?

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have tried so many fixes to enable Outlook 2007+ (07,10,13,16,19) to render my email as I have built it.

I have tried resetting the document & tables. I tried a lot of different containers such as spans, font, p & td's to contain the text, all with the font-size and line-height specified. Put meta tags in, changed the html tag. Yet it is just ignored and all of the text on the email is displayed at font-size: 16px.

Is there a definitive way to guarantee my fonts are displayed at the same size I have coded them to be within the Outlook 07+ versions?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
   <meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document" />
   <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 12" />
   <meta name="Originator" content="Microsoft Word 12" />
   <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <title>blah Terminal</title>
   <link href="" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
   <!--[if mso]>
    <style>
     .fallback-font {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
     }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     <style>
      a:visited {
       color:#f58220;
      }
     </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
     <style type="text/css">
      table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
       border-spacing: 0; 
       mso-line-height-rule: exactly; 
       mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; 
       mso-margin-top-alt: 0; 
       mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
       mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
      }
     </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
     table, tr, td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
     }
    </style>
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if gtemso 9]><xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
     <o:AllowPNG/>
     <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
   </xml><![endif]-->
   <style type="text/css">
    /* Fonts */
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    body,
    p,
    a,
    input,
    textarea,
    button,
    input[type=text],
    input[type=submit],
    table,
    td,
    div,
    span,
    * {
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
     font-weight: bold!important;
     line-height: inherit;
     -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
     -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
     -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
     font-weight: bold!important;
     margin:0;
    }
    body,
    p,
    a,
    input,
    textarea,
    button,
    input[type=text],
    input[type=submit],
    table,
    td,
    div,
    span {
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
     font-weight: bold!important;
    }
    /* END Fonts */

    body {
     margin: 0 auto !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
     height: 100% !important;
     width: 100% !important;
    }
    table,
    td {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
     mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
    }
    img {
     display: block;
     white-space: pre-line;
     -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
    }
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .ExternalClass * {
     line-height: 115%;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     table[class=full-width],
     img[class=full-width],
     table[class=full-width_footer],
     a[class=full-width],
     div[class=full-width] {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     table[class=small-full-width],
     img[class=small-full-width],
     table[class=small-full-width_footer],
     a[class=small-full-width],
     div[class=small-full-width] {
      width: calc(100% - 40px)!important;
      height: auto !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     table[class=full-width-margin] {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      margin: 0 0 20px !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=singleColumn] {
      width: 100% !important;
      float: left !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     table[class=hide],
     td[class=hide],
     tr[class=hide],
     span[class=hide] {
      display: none !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=textJustify],
     a[class=textJustify] {
      text-align: justify !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=textCenter],
     a[class=textCenter] {
      text-align: center !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=textRight],
     a[class=textRight] {
      text-align: right !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     div[class=show] {
      display: block !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=smallTxt],
     a[class=smallTxt],
     span[class=smallTxt] {
      font-size: 11px !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=mediumTxt],
     a[class=mediumTxt],
     span[class=mediumTxt] {
      font-size: 14px !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=largeTxt],
     a[class=largeTxt],
     span[class=largeTxt] {
      font-size: 18px !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     table[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
      display: block !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
      overflow: auto !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-height: none !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     tr[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
      display: block !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
      overflow: auto !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-height: none !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     td[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
      display: block !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
      overflow: auto !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-height: none !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
     [class=mobile-show] {
      overflow: visible !important;
      height: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
      line-height: 100% !important;
     }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
     div[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
      display: block !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
      overflow: auto !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-height: none !important;
     }
    }

    a:visited {
     color: #f58220;
    }
   </style>
   <style sh-font-styles="">
    /* Generated by SharpSpring -- Do not edit */
    [class].font1 {font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial, sans-serif !important;}
    [class].font2 {font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial, sans-serif !important;}
   </style>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#c6c6c6" class="body" style="margin:0;padding:0 !important;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
   <!--[if mso]>
   <style type="text/css">
    body, table, td, a, span {
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    }
   </style>
   <![endif]-->
   <table width="100%" bgcolor="#c6c6c6" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
     <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%">
      <table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width" style="width:640px;color:black;">
       <tr>
        <td width="640" align="center" valign="top">
         <table bgcolor="#68659f" width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width" style="width:640px;">
          <tr>
           <td width="20" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/blah/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="20" style="display:block;">
           </td>
           <td class="hide" width="50" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/blah/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="50" style="display:block;">
           </td>
           <td width="500" align="center" valign="top">
            <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width" style="width:500px;">
             <tr>
              <td width="500" valign="top" height="20" style="line-height:20px;font-size:20px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="500" align="center" valign="top" style="color:#0d233e;line-height:28px;font-size:24px !important;font-weight:bold;font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;">
               <span style="font-size:24px !important;line-height:28px;mso-line-height-alt:32px;">Are you still interested in how</span><br/>
               <span style="font-size:24px !important;line-height:28px;mso-line-height-alt:32px;color:#ffffff;">blah Terminal</span> <span style="font-size:24px !important;line-height:28px;">can help you outperform your Investment Management peers?</span>
              </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="500" valign="top" height="10" style="line-height:10px;font-size:10px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="500" align="center" valign="top" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:12px !important;line-height:16px;mso-line-height-alt:20px;font-weight:bold;font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;">
               <span style="font-size:12px !important;line-height:16px;mso-line-height-alt:20px;">blah Terminal is the smarter platform for Investment Professionals. Innovative design and one-click navigation bring important events to your attention and helps you perform your role more efficiently.</span>
              </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="500" valign="top" height="20" style="line-height:20px;font-size:20px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="500" align="center" valign="top">
               <div class="small-full-width">
                <!--[if mso]>
                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://free-trial.blahterminal.com/?MC=1&FirstName={$firstName}&LastName={$lastName}&Email={$emailAddress}" style="v-text-anchor:middle;width:320px;" arcsize="25%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ffffff">
                 <w:anchorlock/>
                 <center>
                  <![endif]-->
                  <a class="small-full-width" href="https://free-trial.blahterminal.com/?MC=1&FirstName={$firstName}&LastName={$lastName}&Email={$emailAddress}" style="background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:10px;color:#24508c;display:inline-block;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size:12px !important;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:320px;padding:10px 5px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">GET YOUR FREE TRIAL OF blah TERMINAL</a>
                  <!--[if mso]>
                 </center>
                </v:roundrect>
                <![endif]-->
               </div>
              </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="500" valign="top" height="30" style="line-height:30px;font-size:30px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
            </table>
           </td>
           <td class="hide" width="50" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/blah/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="50" style="display:block;">
           </td>
           <td width="20" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/blah/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="20" style="display:block;">
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
 </html>
```

And here are the results:

[image]

If you refer to this image you can see the big title is displayed at a much smaller size on the outlook 2007+ versions.

**Edit:** The **solution** turned out to be, make sure I am applying the styles in the head using a class as well as by targeting attributes (some engines must ignore targeting of elements). Along with removing all inline-style uses of !important.

Here is an updated snippet for you to see:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
  <meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document" />
  <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 12" />
  <meta name="Originator" content="Microsoft Word 12" />
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <title>Example Terminal</title>
  <link href="" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <!--[if mso]>
   <style>
    .fallback-font {
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    }
   </style>
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style>
     a:visited {
      color:#f58220;
     }
    </style>
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
     table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0; 
      mso-line-height-rule: exactly; 
      mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; 
      mso-margin-top-alt: 0; 
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
     }
    </style>
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if gt mso 15]>
   <style type="text/css" media="all">
    table, tr, td {
     border-collapse: collapse;
    }
   </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gtemso 9]><xml>
   <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
   </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  </xml><![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
   /* Fonts */
   h1,
   h2,
   h3,
   h4,
   h5,
   h6,
   body,
   p,
   a,
   input,
   textarea,
   button,
   input[type=text],
   input[type=submit],
   table,
   td,
   div,
   span,
   *,
   .base {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
    line-height: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
   }
   h1,
   h2,
   h3,
   h4,
   h5,
   h6 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
    margin:0;
   }
   body,
   p,
   a,
   input,
   textarea,
   button,
   input[type=text],
   input[type=submit],
   table,
   td,
   div,
   span {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
   }
   /* END Fonts */

   body {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
   }
   table,
   td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
   }
   img {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre-line;
    -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
   }
   a {
    text-decoration: none;
   }
   .ExternalClass * {
    line-height: 115%;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    table[class=full-width],
    img[class=full-width],
    table[class=full-width_footer],
    a[class=full-width],
    div[class=full-width] {
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    table[class=small-full-width],
    img[class=small-full-width],
    table[class=small-full-width_footer],
    a[class=small-full-width],
    div[class=small-full-width] {
     width: calc(100% - 40px)!important;
     height: auto !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    table[class=full-width-margin] {
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto !important;
     margin: 0 0 20px !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=singleColumn] {
     width: 100% !important;
     float: left !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    table[class=hide],
    td[class=hide],
    tr[class=hide],
    span[class=hide] {
     display: none !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=textJustify],
    a[class=textJustify] {
     text-align: justify !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=textCenter],
    a[class=textCenter] {
     text-align: center !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=textRight],
    a[class=textRight] {
     text-align: right !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    div[class=show] {
     display: block !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=smallTxt],
    a[class=smallTxt],
    span[class=smallTxt] {
     font-size: 11px !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=mediumTxt],
    a[class=mediumTxt],
    span[class=mediumTxt] {
     font-size: 14px !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=largeTxt],
    a[class=largeTxt],
    span[class=largeTxt] {
     font-size: 18px !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    table[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
     display: block !important;
     visibility: visible !important;
     overflow: auto !important;
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto !important;
     max-height: none !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    tr[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
     display: block !important;
     visibility: visible !important;
     overflow: auto !important;
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto !important;
     max-height: none !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    td[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
     display: block !important;
     visibility: visible !important;
     overflow: auto !important;
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto !important;
     max-height: none !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    [class=mobile-show] {
     overflow: visible !important;
     height: auto !important;
     display: block !important;
     line-height: 100% !important;
    }
   }

   @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    div[class=singleColumnMobileShow] {
     display: block !important;
     visibility: visible !important;
     overflow: auto !important;
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto !important;
     max-height: none !important;
    }
   }

   a:visited {
    color: #f58220;
   }
  </style>
  <style sh-font-styles="">
   /* Generated by SharpSpring -- Do not edit */
   [class].font1 {font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial, sans-serif !important;}
   [class].font2 {font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial, sans-serif !important;}
  </style>
 </head>

 <body bgcolor="#c6c6c6" class="body" style="margin:0;padding:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
  <!--[if mso]>
  <style type="text/css">
   body, table, td, a, span {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#c6c6c6" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
   <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%">
     <table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width" style="width:640px;color:black;">
      <tr>
       <td width="640" align="center" valign="top">
        <table bgcolor="#68659f" width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width" style="width:640px;">
         <tr>
          <td width="20" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/Example/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="20" style="display:block;">
          </td>
          <td class="hide" width="50" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/Example/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="50" style="display:block;">
          </td>
          <td width="500" align="center" valign="top">
           <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width" style="width:500px;">
            <tr>
             <td width="500" valign="top" height="20" style="line-height:20px;font-size:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td class="base" width="500" align="center" valign="top" style="color:#0d233e;line-height:28px;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
              <span class="base" style="font-size:24px;line-height:28px;mso-line-height-alt:32px;">Are you still interested in how</span><br/>
              <span class="base" style="font-size:24px;line-height:28px;mso-line-height-alt:32px;color:#ffffff;">Example Terminal</span> <span class="base" style="font-size:24px;line-height:28px;">can help you outperform your Investment Management peers?</span>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td width="500" valign="top" height="10" style="line-height:10px;font-size:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td class="base" width="500" align="center" valign="top" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;mso-line-height-alt:20px;font-weight:bold;font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
              <span class="base" style="font-size:12px;line-height:16px;mso-line-height-alt:20px;">Example Terminal is the smarter platform for Investment Professionals. Innovative design and one-click navigation bring important events to your attention and helps you perform your role more efficiently.</span>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td width="500" valign="top" height="20" style="line-height:20px;font-size:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td width="500" align="center" valign="top">
              <div class="small-full-width">
               <!--[if mso]>
               <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://free-trial.Exampleterminal.com/?MC=1&FirstName={$firstName}&LastName={$lastName}&Email={$emailAddress}" style="v-text-anchor:middle;width:320px;" arcsize="25%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ffffff">
                <w:anchorlock/>
                <center>
                 <![endif]-->
                 <a class="small-full-width base" href="https://free-trial.Exampleterminal.com/?MC=1&FirstName={$firstName}&LastName={$lastName}&Email={$emailAddress}" style="background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:10px;color:#24508c;display:inline-block;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:320px;padding:10px 5px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">GET YOUR FREE TRIAL OF Example TERMINAL</a>
                 <!--[if mso]>
                </center>
               </v:roundrect>
               <![endif]-->
              </div>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td width="500" valign="top" height="30" style="line-height:30px;font-size:30px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
          <td class="hide" width="50" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/Example/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="50" style="display:block;">
          </td>
          <td width="20" valign="top"><img alt="" src="https://movemarketing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dragon-force/emails/Example/19/10/25/img/blank.png" width="20" style="display:block;">
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Working code in action:

[image]

Massive thank you to contributors, saved me so much hassle! <3

Comment: two potential reasons for you to consider: 1 those programs might not like media queries, 2 they might not support attribute selectors, try applying the font-sizes using a css class or even id to get the results you want to see. Also, please shorten your code example down to a [mcve]... it looks like you've copy/pasted your entire working file

Comment: This is only 1/3 of the document. Good idea about the attribute selectors. I have been able to fix it removing the !important rule from the inline-styles. Along with applying a font-fix class to the parts containing text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all inline !important statements you've added. That is causing the issues in Outlook.
Not sure why (may be that inline !important statements aren't valid) but there is no need for them in the objects initial state.
**!important should only be used in the head to overwrite your object's initial state.**

I would also shift away from attribute selectors in your head CSS. It's outdated and may not work everywhere any more. I would simply convert them to general class declarations.
i.e.: `table[class=full-width]` becomes `.full-width`.